# FastCGI и ошибка 500

Tags: php, apache2, fastcgi

Вообщем есть сайт на вордпрессе на который 1с кидает данные, аналог связи битрикса и 1с при помощи плагина. В итоге я получаю 500 ошибку так как данных много. Сервер VPS. Настройки типа:

```
max_execution_time
max_input_time
```

и

```
IPCConnectTimeout
IPCCommTimeout
FcgidIOTimeout
FcgidBusyTimeout
FcgidProcessLifeTime
FcgidIdleTimeout
```

Не помогают, всегда получаю:

```
[Tue Mar 12 20:46:31.872460 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1696] (104)Connection 
reset by peer: [client 83.146.116.4:46872] mod_fcgid: error reading data 
from FastCGI server
[Tue Mar 12 20:46:31.872674 2019] [core:error] [pid 1696] [client 
83.146.116.4:46872] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

Вообщем нужна помощь в решении данной проблемы.

Comment: Это лог апача. Покажите лог php, если нет - включите. php.ini `error_log`

Comment: @TotalPusher Он включён вот только где он сохраняется.

Comment: `phpinfo();` искать `error_log`

Answer (score 0):

Открываем конфиг

/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

Увеличиваем лимит до 32МБ

FcgidMaxRequestLen 33554432
MaxRequestLen 33554432

Comment: Дав вот только у меня эти значения:
`FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
MaxRequestLen 1073741824`